# Convert list of ints to strings as key for dict in sort

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict that I want to use as the key for sorting a list.

```
names = {'a': 1,  'b': 0, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5,}
nodes = {'0': 'b', '1': 'a', '2': 'c', '3': 'd', '4': 'e', '5': 'f'}

l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l1.sort(key=names.get)
```

What I want is L1 to be `[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]`.

Obviously the sort line doesn't work as the numbers aren't proper keys for the dict.

I've got the nodes, so my thought is to convert L1 into string values, use the resulting string as the key for the sort, but I just don't know how to do that.

I could do this in some sort of mega loop, but i'm trying to learn python and i'm sure there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Comment: `l1.sort(key=(lambda x, d=nodes:d[str(x)]))`

Comment: `list(map(names.get, sorted(map(nodes.get, map(str, l1)))))` would be the wrong way to do it.

Comment: StevenRumbalski your lambda is slightly different than @Psidom's accepted answer. Any thoughts on which form might be better?

Comment: Just so you know, ints are allowed as dict keys... If you had `nodes={0: 'b', 1: 'a' ...}`, then `l1.sort(key=nodes.get)` would work fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a *lambda* expression as key:

```
l1.sort(key=lambda x: nodes.get(str(x)))         # convert the int to str here
l1
# [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you. Got to get my lambda going better. I tried that one but didn't set it up right.